# How to share multiple cloud flows in Power Automate?

Tags: flow, power-automate, ms-flow, sharing

How can I share multiple cloud flows with a person?

I know how to do it one by one (i.e. clicking on vertical ... and then share), but how to do it for multiple flows without being the admin (i.e. I am the developer)?
[image]

as selecting multiple flows are impossible as shown above.

The other question: what is the name of the default solution that I have developed these flows in?

Comment: Check if there are any PowerShell cmdlets for sharing flows.

Comment: thanks @Ganesh, I found this one https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell and after checking Set-AdminFlowOwnerRole it seems this function needs the flow ID

Comment: You can get flow details using [get-adminflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/get-adminflow?view=pa-ps-latest) cmdlet.